# autofs falling back to nfs version 3 instead of using 4

Tags: automount, nfs

When I mount the nfs-shares manually nfs4 is employed.

But with `autofs` even with the explicit specs in `auto.nfs`

```
foo -fstype=nfs,nfsvers=4,rw    1.2.3.4:/export/foo
```

only nfs-version 3 is used.

`nfsstat -m` reports

```
...
Flags:  rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=131072,wsi
...
```

Specifying `nfs_vers=4` in `/etc/auto.conf` did not help either.

**Q** What must I do to get `autofs` to employ version 4 of nfs?

Comment: Did you try changing `mount_nfs_default_protocol` in `/etc/autofs.conf`?

Comment: @steeldriver nope, setting `mount_nfs_default_protocol = 4` didn't help, still 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between specifying the path between NFS 3 and NFS 4. In my case I had to leave out the `export`. Additionally, I added the `minorversion` but that's not the point.

```
foo   -fstype=nfs,rw,nfsvers=4,minorversion=2   1.2.3.4:/foo
```

After that `nfsstat -m` reports:

```
...
Flags:  rw,relatime,vers=4.2,rsize=131072,wsi...
...
```